# How to automatically get the number of elements through css only

Tags: css, ejs

I am making an autoscrolling carousel on an ejs page in an express app. This carousel depends on the number of images in the carousel to get the spacing and speed right. The number of elements will not be the same everytime, so I have to use CSS to get the number of images in the carousel.

HTML:

```
    <% if (screenshotsLength > 0) { %>
      <div class="slide-body">
        <div class="slider">
          <div class="slide-track">
            <% for (let i=0; i<screenshotsLength; i++) { %>
            <div class="slide">
              <a href="<%= game.screenshots[i].url %>" target="_blank"><img src="<%= game.screenshots[i].url %>" alt="screenshot" class="img-scroll"></a>
            </div>
            <% } %>
            <!-- same slides doubled -->
            <% for (let i=0; i<screenshotsLength; i++) { %>
            <div class="slide">
              <a href="<%= game.screenshots[i].url %>" target="_blank"><img src="<%= game.screenshots[i].url %>" alt="screenshot" class="img-scroll"></a>
            </div>
            <% } %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% } %>
```

CSS:

```
.slide-body {
  min-height: 20vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.slider {
  height: 250px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide-track {
  counter-reset: screenshot-counter 0;
  display: flex;
  width: calc((screenshot-counter) * 250px);
  animation: scroll 40s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(calc(-250px * (screenshot-counter/2)));
  }
}

.slide {
  height: 200px;
  width: 250px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px;
  perspective: 100px;
}

.slide-track .slide {
  counter-increment: screenshot-counter 1;
}

.slide:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.img-scroll {
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.img-scroll:hover {
  transform: translateZ(20px);
}

/* gradient shadows */

.slider::before,
.slider::after {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(46,52,64,1) 0%, 
  rgba(46,52,64,0) 100%);
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 15%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.slider::before {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.slider::after {
  right: -1;
  top: 0;
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}
```

I tried using counter() to get the number of elements that way, but my carousel doesn't move. I tried simply adding a number in front of each image first and that worked out, so my code is keeping count, but I'm unsure what else is wrong. The `width: calc((screenshot-counter) * 250px);` line in the css part of inspect element says "invalid property value", but I'm unsure what to do here.

Comment: Hi @Sami, as per my understanding there is no way to do this with CSS only, We have to use Javascript for that. If you want to use Js let me know , I will share the solution for that. Also someone will solve this with CSS only , I am also querious to know this solution.

Comment: If you could tell me how you do this with javascript that would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already seem to have the number of slides in screenshotsLength.

If you set a CSS variable to that length then you could use it in the keyframes instead of screenshot-counter / 2.

```
<% if (screenshotsLength > 0) { %>
  <div class="slide-body" style="--number: <%= screenshotsLength %> ">
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slide-track">
        <% for (let i=0; i<screenshotsLength; i++) { %>
        <div class="slide">
          <a href="<%= game.screenshots[i].url %>" target="_blank"><img src="<%= game.screenshots[i].url %>" alt="screenshot" class="img-scroll"></a>
        </div>
        <% } %>
        <!-- same slides doubled -->
        <% for (let i=0; i<screenshotsLength; i++) { %>
        <div class="slide">
          <a href="<%= game.screenshots[i].url %>" target="_blank"><img src="<%= game.screenshots[i].url %>" alt="screenshot" class="img-scroll"></a>
        </div>
        <% } %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% } %>
```

and then in the CSS:

```
.slide-body {
  min-height: 20vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.slider {
  height: 250px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide-track {
  counter-reset: screenshot-counter 0;
  display: flex;
  width: calc((screenshot-counter) * 250px);
  animation: scroll 40s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(calc(-250px * var(--number)));
  }
}

.slide {
  height: 200px;
  width: 250px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px;
  perspective: 100px;
}

.slide-track .slide {
  counter-increment: screenshot-counter 1;
}

.slide:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.img-scroll {
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.img-scroll:hover {
  transform: translateZ(20px);
}

/* gradient shadows */

.slider::before,
.slider::after {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(46,52,64,1) 0%, 
  rgba(46,52,64,0) 100%);
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 15%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.slider::before {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.slider::after {
  right: -1;
  top: 0;
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}
```

Note: there is padding on each slide so is the amount you are moving actually correct?

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I didn't realize I could use a variable carried over from express into css. Thanks!